# Order of tech_array and bio_array

Tags: brightway

Context: I have used `ParameterVectorLCA` in different LCAs that may have been generated in different `projects`. I have stored the resulting `params`. I would like to ensure the `params` are in the same order.

What I know:
 - I know that the elements of these parameter arrays have two fields that refer to the `inputs` and `outputs`
 - I know that the `activity_dict` and the `bio_dict` can tell us what these `inputs` and `outputs` refer to
 - I know that it is possible to reorder `supply arrays` and `inventory_matrices` from one project to that of another by using the respective `activity_dict` and the `bio_dict`

What I don't know:
  - If my `activity_dict` and `bio_dict` are the same for both LCAs, am I garanteed that the order of my `params` is the same?
 - If my `activity_dict` and `bio_dict` are NOT the same, can I reorder my `params`? My strategy would be to:

- Select one of my LCAs as the "reference"
- For the other LCAs, change the `input` and `output` numbers in the `tech_params` and `bio_params` to those of the reference LCA (by using the `activity_dict` and `bio_dict`)
- Attribute an index to the string representations of each parameter in the `tech_param` and `bio_param`.
- Find the index for the corresponding string representation of paramters in the `tech_param` and `bio_param` of the LCA I want to reorder.
- Reorder using reindexing.

Would this do it? Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameter arrays in a project will always be sorted in the same order when [processed](https://bitbucket.org/cmutel/brightway2-data/src/4ef52f9bfb169f4625e838d1461e4ff89be710d5/bw2data/backends/peewee/database.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#database.py-454) (you can see the [fields used when sorting](https://bitbucket.org/cmutel/brightway2-data/src/4ef52f9bfb169f4625e838d1461e4ff89be710d5/bw2data/data_store.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#data_store.py-245)). Moreover, the order that arrays are concatenated into e.g. `tech_params` will be the same within a project (arrays are sorted based on [their filename](https://bitbucket.org/cmutel/brightway2-calc/src/9a8887757cdec533a14b16d1a4151b95fef8a97f/bw2calc/utils.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#utils.py-22)). Finally, the way that `activity_dict`, etc. are constructed is also guaranteed to [be consistent](https://bitbucket.org/cmutel/brightway2-calc/src/9a8887757cdec533a14b16d1a4151b95fef8a97f/bw2calc/indexing.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#indexing.py-49). As you said, however, the `input` and `output` values can be completely different from project to project.

- If my activity_dict and bio_dict are the same for both LCAs, am I guaranteed that the order of my params is the same?

Yes.

- If my activity_dict and bio_dict are NOT the same, can I reorder my params?

Trickier.

- For the other LCAs, change the input and output numbers in the tech_params and bio_params to those of the reference LCA (by using the activity_dict and bio_dict)

This doesn't work because `activity_dict` goes from keys to matrix columns; the values in `input` are `mapping` values. So you would need access to `mapping to use this strategy.

The easiest by far would be to reorder *both* param arrays, forgetting the `mapping` values (which can vary from project to project), and instead use activity keys (which I assume are the same). Then you can easily sort each array by input key, output key, amount, etc. (see `dtype_fields_order`; there are duplicate exchanges with the same input and output) and be confidant that you are getting the same order.

This would be a nice addition to a utilities library, but make sure to write tests first!