# Efficiently saving sampled matrix values in Brightway

Tags: brightway

I would like to hstack and store sampled values for the technosphere and biosphere matrices for efficient reuse (e.g. for sensitivity analyses). Focusing on the technosphere matrix for now, here is what I have:

- Saved CSR sparse matrices, one per Monte Carlo iteration
- the `activity_dict` and the `product_dict` (scope=LCA object)
- the `mapping` dictionaries (scope=project)

What I ultimately want is  :

(1) an array where rows are non-zero elements from my technosphere matrices and columns are different Monte Carlo iterations; and

(2) some way of determining what the *i*th row refers to.

I know I could simply:

- convert my CSR sparse matrix to COO (i.e. `coo_matrix = mc.technosphere_matrix.tocoo()`)and hstack the resulting COO matrix `data`
- Store the `row` and `col` for one coo_matrix as arrays (e.g. `coo_rows=coo_matrix.row` and `coo_cols=coo_matrix.col`). These indices would be the same for all my matrices.
- Use the reverse of the `product_dict` and `activity_dict` to determine what each element refers to. For example, to know what the *i*th row in my hstacked data refers to, I could use `reverse_activity_dict[coo_cols[i]]` to get my
  activity name `reverse_product_dict[coo_rows[i]]` to get my product.

This, however, does not take advantage of [already optimized brightway functions](https://bitbucket.org/cmutel/brightway2-calc/src/c4bf5638053415e082fab63146c1177495824818/bw2calc/indexing.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default)...I just fail to see *how* to use these.

The answer may lay [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43620285/order-of-tech-array-and-bio-array), but just out of reach...

As a bonus: my MC iterations may come from different projects with different `mapping`s (but with identical database names).

Answer (score 0):

I've finally decided on the following strategy for storage:

- Save one array of data, as described above.
- Save a list of indices, where indices are defined as `(input key, output key, type)`. As was shown [elsewhere](https://github.com/PascalLesage/brightway2-presamples/blob/master/presamples/loader.py#L249), these can efficiently be used with the Brightway 
  [`MatrixBuilder`](https://bitbucket.org/cmutel/brightway2-calc/src/c4bf5638053415e082fab63146c1177495824818/bw2calc/matrices.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#matrices.py-11) class.